# Send axios post request error message from node js server to client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

How can I send a node JS Axios request error message? I don't want to print the error in the console, I want to send it to the application.

For instance, if I am testing on postman and i hit `localhost:8080/list/2` and `2` is the wrong id, instead of endlessly showing `sending request`, I want the specific JSON error message returned.

`**server.js** proxy server running on localhost:8000 makes request to another endpoint`

```
app.get("/list/:id", function (req, res) {
  const { id } = req.params;
  axios
    .get(`${BASE_URL}/list/` + id)
    .then((response) => {
     res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       if(error.response) {
            res.send(error.response)
        }
    });
});
```

**2. How can this error message be used in an Axios request on the client side?**

```
const getList = () => {

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/list", {
          params: {
            id: '4'
          }
        })
      .then((resp) => {
        const data = resp.data; 
        console.log(resp.data)

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };
```

Comment: When you pass correct id do you see response in postman? if yes then my guess is your  error object doesn't have response property and that's why it doesn't go inside if block.

Comment: You've confused route and query parameters. Use `axios.get("http://localhost:8000/list/4")` instead. The `params` option is for creating query parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error.response` is an Axios Response object which doesn't serialise to JSON very well.

See [Axios - Handling Errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors).

You should respond with the upstream response status and data

```js
app.get("/list/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/list/${id}`, {
      baseURL: BASE_URL,
    });
    res.send(data);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      res
        .status(err.response.status) // proxy the status
        .send(err.response.data); // proxy the data
    }
    next(err); // some other error
  }
});
```

---

FYI, the Axios `params` option is for constructing URL query parameters. Your client-side request should use

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:8000/list/4")
```

---

Another FYI, Express has a much simpler proxy library - [express-http-proxy](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy)

```js
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

app.use("/list", proxy(BASE_URL, {
  https: true,
  proxyReqPathResolver: (req) => req.originalUrl,
}));
```